# Удалил пользователя из sudoers, теперь Ubuntu требует пароль администратора. Как исправить?

Tags: ubuntu, пароль

Моего основного пользователя (по совместительству единственного и бывшего администратора) я случайно удалил из группы sudoers. почитал в интернете, что можно через меню grub сбросить пароль админа, т.к вместо пароля пользователя требует пароль администратора, но... У меня его (grub) нет, вместо grub boot-меню, с возможностью выбора запуска одной из двух одинаковых ос (не пойму вообще, почему у меня их две). И я ничего, абсолютно ничего не могу делать: ни запускать приложения через терминал (и через код на любом яп), ни загрузочные файлы, ни подключаться к ранее неизвестной wi-fi сети...

[image: вот ,к примеру, убунту требует пароль админа при попытке подключения к незнакомой wi-fi сети]
*вот ,к примеру, убунту требует пароль админа при попытке подключения к незнакомой wi-fi сети*

[image: boot-меню такое же, только из выбора ubuntu 20.04 и ubuntu 20.04]
*boot-меню такое же, только из выбора ubuntu 20.04 и ubuntu 20.04*

Comment: Если диск не зашифрован, то проще загрузится с флешки и поправить руками

Comment: а поправить надо вот это: `я случайно удалил из группы sudoers`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin , я с удовольствием! Только не подскажете, как это сделать в моей ситуации?) Так или иначе, нужно заходить в recovery-меню. А без grub я не знаю, как это сделать

Comment: Ну блин. `linux clear paasword`. https://habr.com/ru/post/54103/ https://losst.ru/sbros-parolya-ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

На будущее тем, кто столкнётся с такой же проблемой, как и я. Мне помогла только переустановка ОС. Если вам действительно хочется работать на убунту, переустановите, всё будет работать нормально (я проверил во время первой переустановки). Но мне больше нравится windows, поэтому я поставил его. Я пользовался андроидом и приложением ventoy для создания загрузочной флэшки по причинам названным в описании вопроса. Для ubuntu выбор немного больше-можете использовать ещё и Etchdroid. Это те программы, которые я сам использовал и вам рекомендую.

PS Хочу сказать, что если вы наткнётесь на iso 2 usb, не устанавливайте. У меня ни разу нормально образ убунту не записался на флэшку через это приложение. На одном устройстве записал коряво-появлялась ошибка при установке непосредственно на компьютер, а на другом вообще процесс записи останавливался.

Comment: Я не думаю, что ваш текст можно считать ответом. Ведь можно и диск отформатировать, а можно и сервер новый купить - но это не сделает это ответом на вопрос, как в текущей системе восстановить.

Comment: Видимо, самый правильный совет из первого комментария - загрузиться с флешки и поправить руками - вы решили проигнорировать, зря :(